# How to Instantiate Class Object from CSV Values?

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, windows-8, windows-runtime

Hi I am trying to create a general CSV parser in Windows 8 App using C#. I want to create a parser in which when I pass the Type T and the string CSV and Object I should get the object populated something like this:

```
T obj = ParserCSV<T>(CSVString);
```

Currently I am able to get a sample that's there on MSDN link for that http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSV-Parser-for-WinRT-42e0f4d0

In this we parse the csv string and get the collection of Key Value pair. But then to convert to object we need to find the specific key and map that to the object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You will only be able to assume that the CSV values are of type string. Unless you encode the CSV values themselves and parse those differently for each required type what you want is not possible. Use XML.

Comment: Can't I map the property name with the Key name?

Comment: I see what you are saying now, sorry. Yes, you can do this. Give me a second I will try and help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method; this creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that best matches the specified parameters. An example of it's use in your case would be

```
Activator.CreateInstance("myAssemblyName", "myType")
```

So if you had the following class

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name;
    public Person() { }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this._name = value; }
    }
}
```

You could create an object instance using something like the following:

```
ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance("PersonInfo", "Person");
Person p = (Person) handle.Unwrap();
p.Name = "Samuel";
Console.WriteLine(p);
```

which would print "Samuel". In your case, for each `KeyValuePair` you can instantiate the relevant object using the above.

I hope this helps.

---

*Edit. To address additional question.*

```
Dictionary<String, String> someDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
someDict = GetDictOfKvpFromCsv(); // Get the dictionary from your CSV.
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> kvp in someDict)
{
    ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    ISomeType t = (ISomeType)handle.Unwrap();
    // Do other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks it really helps. But can I take the property Name and pass it as string to the KeyValue Pair and get the value for it?

Comment: Yes. But you have not shown what this 'Key Value pair' is. is this a `KeyValuePair<String, String>` or what? Please remember to upvote if it was useful and mark as answer if it is the answer...

Comment: Yes its KeyValuePair<String, String> pair.